# Static handler for fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-handler

I read [this piece](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) about using a static Handler inner class to avoid memory leak.

I put the inner class in a activity class`BaseActivity` which other activities extend. The handler works fine in activity classes:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Handler handler = new StaticHandler(this);

    public static class StaticHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<BaseActivity> mActivity;

        public StaticHandler(BaseActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<BaseActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            BaseActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to use a handler in fragment, is it possible to call the `StaticHandler` from the Base Activity? I can't find a way to do it. Should I create another static handler in the fragment class? Is it better to pass the `handler` from BaseActivity to the fragment instead of instantiating a new one in the fragment?

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){....};
           Handler handler = new BaseActivity.StaticHandler(getActivity()); // It won't work because the getActivity() doesn't match BaseActivity 
           handler.post(runnable)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `BaseActivity` extending `AppCompatActivity` so pass `AppCompatActivity` Context from Fragment as:

```
Handler handler = new BaseActivity.StaticHandler((BaseActivity)getActivity());
```

Also in `BaseActivity` initialize  `handler` object inside any method instead of at class level.